# Is it possible to having analogous members in different classes with different return types?

Tags: c++

If one defines a class `multiA` holding a vector of instances of class `A`, is there a way to have `multiA` "inherit" (for lack of a better term) all the public member functions of A, returning a `std::vector` with the output?

```
#include <vector>

class A {
 public:
    A();
    float member1();
    float member2();
    // ...
};

class multiA {
 public:
    multiA();

    // ...
    //  std::vector<float> member1();

 protected:
    std::vector<A> data;
};
```

I understand I can just define an analogous member function in `multiA`, but would require me change it if any member of `A` is rewritten, and a more general approach would maybe allow me to use `multiA` as  template to several classes? I am wondering if there is way to "automatically" create members for `multiA` based on `A` and change their return type.

Comment: Inheritance. `class Derived : public Base` etc.

Comment: That won't change the return type of each inherited member though? I would still need to redefine each member, even if it's a wrapper to STL `transform`, for instance.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this in C++. It's possible to write a function template that takes another function and a vector as argument and returns a vector of results (I guess that's `std::transform`), but it is not possible to generate a class that uses it automatically.

Comment: You can however write a program (in whatever language you prefer) to generate C++ code for the class automatically i.e. you can write a custom pre-processor.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with plain c++.
Maybe if you employ some heavy macro magic one would be able to automate this for the types for which it is even possible, but the effort you need to put in this will almost never be worth it.
Note that you would first need to define all operations possible on `A` to also implement on `std::vector<A>`, which is already pretty hard to automate.